# Google maps doesn't work on the HTC?

Tags: android, google-maps

I am developing application with Google Map.

I've tested on the emulator and saw error line In the log:

```
01-23 16:04:28.453: ERROR/MapActivity(733): Couldn't get connection factory client
```

But it worked fine on the emulator.

Then I've signed the application and created its .apk file. I've put it on the web server downloaded and installed it on the real device (it is HTC with Verizon).

But my application didn't appear google maps on the device. I've checked API key and other configuration. Everything was ok. But google maps didn't work.

Have you faced to problem same as mine ?

Please suggest.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the signed version work on the emulator too?

Comment: HTC is a company not a device.  You mention it is HTC with Verizon, which would mean it is the HTC Droid Eris device.  Not that I think it matters in your case, but the title of your question looks silly.  Jeff has your answer below.

Comment: Thanks guys, I've tested recently on the Emulator (not computer signed. On the another computer's emulator). It didn't work. 

So, I've made a wrong API key. 
Is it right ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like the maps API key you are using is not associated with the certificate you are signing the application with.

You will typically need to register for two maps API keys - one associated with the debug certificate that automatically signs each build that you deploy to the emulator during development, and another associated with your production certificate that you sign your APK with prior to publishing on the market.

http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html